# How is make_heap in C++ implemented to have complexity of 3N?

Tags: c++, algorithm, heap

I wonder what's the algorithm of make_heap in  in C++ such that the complexity is 3*N? Only way I can think of to make a heap by inserting elements have complexity of O(N Log N). Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can read about it from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap

Comment: @UncleBens That link actually shows that the cost is *2n*, so why does `std::make_heap()` take *3n*?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You represent the heap as an array.  The two elements below the `i`'th element are at positions `2i+1` and `2i+2`.  If the array has `n` elements then, starting from the end, take each element, and let it "fall" to the right place in the heap.  This is `O(n)` to run.

Why?  Well for `n/2` of the elements there are no children.  For `n/4` there is a subtree of height 1.  For `n/8` there is a subtree of height 2.  For `n/16` a subtree of height 3.  And so on.  So we get the series `n/22 + 2n/23 + 3n/24 + ... = (n/2)(1 * (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + . ...) + (1/2) * (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + . ...) + (1/4) * (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + . ...) + ...) = (n/2) * (1 * 1 + (1/2) * 1 + (1/4) * 1 + ...) = (n/2) * 2 = n`.  Or, formatted maybe more readably to see the geometric series that are being summed:

```
n/2^2 + 2n/2^3 + 3n/2^4 + ...
  = (n/2^2 +  n/2^3 +  n/2^4 + ...)
           + (n/2^3 +  n/2^4 + ...)
                    + (n/2^4 + ...)
    + ...
  = n/2^2 (1 + 1/2 + 1/2^4 + ...)
           + n/2^3 (1 + 1/2 + 1/2^3 + ...)
                    + n/2^4 (1 + 1/2 + 1/2^3 + ...)
    + ...
  = n/2^2 * 2
           + n/2^3 * 2
                    + n/2^4 * 2
    + ...
  = n/2 + n/2^2 + n/2^3 + ...
  = n(1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...)
  = n
```

And the trick we used repeatedly is that we can sum the geometric series with

```
1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...
   = (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...) (1 - 1/2)/(1 - 1/2)
   = (1 * (1 - 1/2)
        + 1/2 * (1 - 1/2)
              + 1/4 * (1 - 1/2)
                    + 1/8 * (1 - 1/2)
                          + ...) / (1 - 1/2)
   = (1 - 1/2
        + 1/2 - 1/4
              + 1/4 - 1/8
                    + 1/8 - 1/16
                          + ...) / (1 - 1/2)
   = 1 / (1 - 1/2)
   = 1 / (1/2)
   = 2
```

So the total number of "see if I need to fall one more, and if so which way do I fall? comparisons comes to `n`.  But you get round-off from discretization, so you always come out to less than `n` sets of swaps to figure out.  Each of which requires at most 3 comparisons.  (Compare root to each child to see if it needs to fall, then the children to each other if the root was larger than both children.)

Comment: Hi , Could you please explain the summation part ?
 "n/2^2 + 2*n/2^3 + 3*n/2^4 + .." Could not catch on to this step...

Comment: @AdhirajChattopadhyay I added the calculation reformatted to make the geometric series easier to see.  Unfortunately I had to use `^` because I can't easily format this way and get proper superscripts.